# Using dircolors, how do I change the color of my subversion folders

Tags: colors, ls

Below is a sample of my dircolors file, I want subversion folders (.svn) to be colored, but i guess the extension section only applies to file names.

How do i set colors for directories with certain names?

```
NORMAL 00   # global default, although everything should be something.
FILE   00   # normal file
DIR    35   # directory
LINK   01;36    # symbolic link
FIFO   40;33    # pipe
SOCK   01;35    # socket
BLK    40;33;01 # block device driver
CHR    40;33;01 # character device driver

# This is for files with execute permission:
EXEC 01;32

# List any file extensions like '.gz' or '.tar' that you would like ls
# to colorize below. Put the extension, a space, and the color init string.
# (and any comments you want to add after a '#')
*~    01;33;41 # stuff we hate to find laying around (flashing red)
.svn  37
.cmd  01;32 # executables (bright green)
.exe  01;32
.com  01;32
.btm  01;32
```

Comment: What OS? I’m unfamiliar with dircolors.

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11288821/754997 uses a Perl script to colorize the output from ls. You then use that script instead of ls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way:

```
diff --git a/src/ls.c b/src/ls.c
index 680a7c3..d316eb6 100644
--- a/src/ls.c
+++ b/src/ls.c
@@ -4226,7 +4226,7 @@ print_color_indicator (const struct fileinfo *f, bool symlink_target)

   /* Check the file's suffix only if still classified as C_FILE.  */
   ext = NULL;
-  if (type == C_FILE)
+  if (type == C_FILE || type == C_DIR)
     {
       /* Test if NAME has a recognized suffix.  */
```

[image]

Comment: Notice that without modifying `ls` source code, what you are asking for is not possible. (See the first comment `/* … */` above.)

Comment: Thanks, so i guess i won't be modifying the source code (i don't have that level of access on the machines at work.

Comment: @Roy: There is nothing that prevents you from compiling your own `ls` and place it in your PATH. Quite easy: `git clone git://git.sv.gnu.org/coreutils`, edit one line of `src/ls.c`, `./bootstrap`, `./configure`, `make`, `cp src/ls ~/bin`, and you're done :-)